# What role do the Build() and Run() function play in an ASP.Net Core web application?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am really new for programming started to development on .NET core Web API development.

This is the piece of code :

```
namespace time_api
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

I have spent more hours to understand this code piece. I understand that it is calling a static method `CreateWebHostBuilder`. But I really do not understand what are those `.Build() & .Run()`.
It is like a method(CreateWebHostBuilder) calling another method and another method ?

What is the meaning of having  `=>` here ?

Please help me to understand

Comment: In the future you should try to ask more specific questions, and also to research things like the API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilder.build?view=aspnetcore-2.2 and the language syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is what is happening in a nutshell.

1. You're calling your own static method that constructs an `IWebHostBuilder` which is an interface whose purpose is to allow you to configure an ASP.Net hosting environment.
2. You're then calling an instance method, `Build`, on the `IWebHostBuilder` object that your static function returned.

   - The `Build` function takes the configuration, extensions, and so on that is stored on the `IWebHostBuilder` implementation and uses it to construct the `IWebHost` instance that will actually be running listening for HTTP requests to handle.
3. You're finally calling the `Run` method on the `IWebHost` that the `IWebHostBuilder.Build` method returned.

   - This is the method that actually listens for HTTP requests, maps the requests to one of your controllers, instantiates that controller along with any dependencies, and invokes the action methods.
   - This method "blocks", or does not return, until something causes your program to exit (i.e. you hit Ctrl+C).

The `=>` after the `CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)` declaration is a new-ish way of declaring a method body called an "expression-bodied member." In this case it is equivalent to the following

```cs
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
```

The same symbol `=>` can be used to create a "lambda", or anonymous function, in a case where a delegate or expression is expected.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration.Please give some time to go through the resources you provided. also I noted the comment you have mentioned to my question and In future I will ask more specific questions.Thank you very much.